# Titanium Android: Images and Memory

Tags: android, image, memory, titanium

I'm having problems with using images in both the Android emulator and the Galaxy S2.  I'm not writing natively I'm using Titanium.

If I comment out any references to images in my app, it runs perfectly.  I'm have checked for memory leaks and found none.

The error I get in the console is:

```
I/dalvikvm-heap( 1867): Clamp target GC heap from 24.689MB to 24.000MB
E/GraphicsJNI( 1867): VM won't let us allocate 1183156 bytes
D/dalvikvm( 1867): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 45% free 4499K/8135K, external 16311K/16603K, paused 48ms
E/TiDrawableReference( 1867): (main) [3335,78053] Unable to load bitmap. Not enough memory: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
E/TiDrawableReference( 1867): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

The app runs perfectly in iOS, are there any tips to better handle image management with Titanium and Android?

SDK: 1.8.2
Runtime: V8

Comment: It is not really a leak, it is just that the phone don't got enough memory to display large pictures. Try your code, but use a small image, if that works, then you have to cut the picture into chunks (got sample code for android SDK). But first try it with smaller images.

Comment: It appears it was down to using a backgroundImage fullScreen, I've totally changed the screen layout to avoid this and job done it works!  Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to memory issue with emulator. The simplest solution is to add below lines in tiapp.xml file

```
<property name="ti.android.threadstacksize" type="int">131072</property>
<property name="ti.android.httpclient.maxbuffersize" type="int">131072</property>
```

Comment: This issue happens not only on emulator. I got the `Not enough memory: null` error when made 8MP photo from the app and tried to resize it.

Answer (score 1):

Well This is not Titanium Concerned.Because Android doesn't allow High Resolution Files or large weight Images from the Gallery or externalStorage.So You must use the Compressed Images or resized image.

Following Code might help You.Best of Luck...

```
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                    File f = new File(selectedImagePath);
                    bmImg = decodeFile(f);//BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
                    takePhotoImg.setImageBitmap(imageManipulation.getResizedBitmap(
                            bmImg, 240, 160));

                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
                    timeStamp = s.format(new Date());
                    File f1 = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile"+ "test"+timeStamp+".jpg");
                    try {
                        f1.createNewFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //write the bytes in file
                    FileOutputStream fo;
                    try {
                        fo = new FileOutputStream(f1);
                        try {
                            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                            System.out.println("#########File is being Written=========!!!!!");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem by adding the following code to tiapp.xml

`<application android:largeHeap="true">`

View example under "Requesting a large heap from Dalvik" in the following url:

https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/tiapp_xml_and_timodule_xml_reference.html#tiapp.xmlandtimodule.xmlReference-Androidspecificapplicationproperties